# I need help solving this logarithmic equation: $\log(3)=\log2+\log(−1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

So far I have found that the domain is $x>1.$
And that the base of the logs are $10,$ but I never have encountered an equation like this one. And I am not sure how to begin solving it. Would I subtract one of the logs to get all logs on one side of the equation?

Comment: solve $3x=2(x-1)$

Comment: How did you obtain this new equation? Could you show me step by step? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: $\log a + \log b = \log(a\times b).$

Comment: Ah I see now. I have to condense the equation first then solve. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @gnatgnat2019 Yes and you can solve by injectivity of $\log$ wich is a fundamental condition. Think to $$\sin A= \sin B \not\rightarrow A=B$$

Comment: I need help interpreting this problem.  If we formally solve $3x=2(x-1)$ the argunent oif the logs are negative.  Are we supposed to use complex algebra or claim no solution within the domain?

Comment: @OscarLanzi If the result obtained is not in the domain of the original expression then there are not solutions.

Comment: Question says domain has to have positive arguments, which answer my comments.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use that

- $\log A +\log B = \log AB$ (rule obtained by the definition of $\log$)
- $\log A= \log B \iff A=B$ (by injectivity of $\log$ function)

then

$$\log(3)=\log2+\log(−1) \iff \log(3)=\log\left[2(−1)\right]\iff 3x=2(x-1)$$

with the condition $x>1$.

Comment: Did you mean $x-1$ where you typed $x+1$?  It gets complex, because $x<0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes of course I fix that typo! Thanks

Comment: This is what I got from applying the rules you guys gave me:

Comment: 3x=log[2(x-1)] @user

Comment: @gnatgnat2019:  it should be $3x=2(x-1)$

Comment: But how did you get rid of the logs? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @gnatgnat2019 As noticed, the fundamental step is that $\log A= \log B \iff A=B$.

Comment: exponentiate both sides of the equation

Comment: Ah okay, let me go ahead and do that.

Comment: I obtained the solution x=-2, which is not in the domain of x>1

Comment: @user: $\log (e^{2 \pi i})=\log (e^0)$, but $2\pi i\ne 0$

Comment: @gnatgnat2019 That's fine! Then no solutions.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm referring to reals of course! :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your guys help! I genuinely appreciate it. @user

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\log a + \log b=\log ab$

$\log 2 + \log (x-1)= \log(2(x-1))$

Comment: Give me a moment while I solve please. @J.W Tanner

Comment: So this the equation I got when I applied the rules you mentioned.

Comment: 3x=log[2(x-1)] @J.W Tanner

Answer (score 1):

The emperor is wearing no clothes.  If you solve $3x=2(x-1)$ as directed in other answers you find $x$ is not in the required domain $x>1$.

Comment: I agree, so $+1$

Answer (score 0):

It has no solutions since we know $ x > 1 $and solving the equation $ 3x = 2x - 2 $ we get $x=-2$ which is absurd.